# Angluarjs reverse an array giving errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I would like to reverse an array.

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index | reverse"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
      <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span></li>
   </ul>
```

And the JS

```
var myfirstApp = angular.module('myfirstApp', []);

myfirstApp.filter('reverse', function() {
    return function(items) {
        return items.slice().reverse();
    };
});
```

In my controller I have

```
    $scope.todos = [ 
        {text: 'Learn AngularJS', done:false},
        {text: 'Build an app', done:false}


    ];
```

but Im getting "Error: items.slice is not a function" , and if I remove slide I get the same for reverse. Is there an issue with how its reading the array?

Comment: try to check `items` using console.log if its null or anything

Comment: would be helpful if you could create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: as I suspected Im getting 0 in the log, yes I thought I was missing something obvious but I may create a jsfiddle now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code of your ng-repeat

```
todo in todos  | reverse track by $index
```

Answer (score 0):

.reverse(); dosn't return anything, it just reverses the array, but does not return the reversed array. 
You should do:

```
var myfirstApp = angular.module('myfirstApp', []);

myfirstApp.filter('reverse', function() {
    return function(items) {
        items.reverse();
        return items;
    };
});
```

Comment: Although this makes for better code this wasnt actually the issue , Sais answer is correct, but thanks